# Emacs saving automatically (*not* auto-save)

Tags: emacs, haskell

When I edit Haskell files, Emacs saves the file whenever I stop typing for more than a second.  This is *not* auto-save mode, as it's overwriting the original file.  Also, I disabled auto-save mode, and it still happens.  It doesn't happen if I edit Java files or plain text files.  How can I figure out what's happening, or better yet, stop it?

Comment: You should take a look at `haskell-mode.el`. Try to search `save` word there -- if You know elisp. Otherwise -- find the email of the author (in the top of `haskell-mode.el`) -- and drop him an email about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you can try:

- Try `M-x debug-on-entry save-buffer` (or `save-current-buffer` etc.
- `M-: (add-hook 'before-save-hook '(lambda () (debug)))`

The debugger should open whenever Emacs tries to save a buffer, so you can see what function (farther down the stack is asking for the buffer to be saved.

Comment: For unrelated reasons, I reinstalled my OS, and haskell-mode is working now.  Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: I believe this is still an issue for me. While having a file watch on the whole directory, it seems to save the file after every few keystrokes. I've also tried setting the breakpoints, but none of these seem to get triggered.